Curl timeout when executing leapp preupgrade to upgrade RHEL from 8.10 to 9.4
I am trying to upgrade RHEL from 8.10 to 9.4 with the leapp preupgrade command, and timeout error is reported:

dnf.exceptions.RepoError: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-8&arch=x86_64&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir [Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds]

Here is the full output of the command:
$ sudo leapp preupgrade
[sudo] password for cmadmin: 
==> Processing phase `configuration_phase`
====> * ipu_workflow_config
        IPU workflow config actor
==> Processing phase `FactsCollection`
====> * scan_subscription_manager_info
        Scans the current system for subscription manager information
====> * scan_custom_modifications_actor
        Collects information about files in leapp directories that have been modified or newly added.
====> * read_openssh_config
        Collect information about the OpenSSH configuration.
====> * network_manager_connection_scanner
        Scan NetworkManager connection keyfiles
====> * udevadm_info
        Produces data exported by the "udevadm info" command.
====> * nis_scanner
        Collect information about the NIS packages configuration.
====> * firewalld_collect_global_config
        This actor reads firewalld's configuration and produces Model
====> * scan_source_files
        Scan files (explicitly specified) of the source system.
====> * common_leapp_dracut_modules
        Influences the generation of the initram disk
====> * roce_scanner
        Detect active RoCE NICs on IBM Z machines.
====> * copy_dnf_conf_into_target_userspace
        Copy dnf.conf into target userspace
====> * scan_systemd_source
        Provides info about systemd on the source system
====> * scanmemory
        Scan Memory of the machine.
====> * check_custom_network_scripts
        Check the existence of custom network-scripts and warn user about possible
====> * rpm_scanner
        Provides data about installed RPM Packages.
Process Process-218:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 573, in load
    ret = self._repo.load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libdnf/repo.py", line 397, in load
    return _repo.Repo_load(self)
libdnf._error.Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-8&arch=x86_64&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir [Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/leapp/repository/actor_definition.py", line 74, in _do_run
    actor_instance.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/leapp/actors/__init__.py", line 289, in run
    self.process(*args)
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/actors/rpmscanner/actor.py", line 20, in process
    rpmscanner.process()
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/actors/rpmscanner/libraries/rpmscanner.py", line 111, in process
    rpm_streams = map_modular_rpms_to_modules()
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/actors/rpmscanner/libraries/rpmscanner.py", line 87, in map_modular_rpms_to_modules
    modules = module_lib.get_modules()
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/libraries/module.py", line 57, in get_modules
    base = _create_or_get_dnf_base(base)
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/libraries/module.py", line 47, in _create_or_get_dnf_base
    base.fill_sack()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 405, in fill_sack
    self._add_repo_to_sack(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 140, in _add_repo_to_sack
    repo.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 580, in load
    raise dnf.exceptions.RepoError(str(e))
dnf.exceptions.RepoError: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-8&arch=x86_64&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir [Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds]
2024-10-02 09:37:15.472 ERROR    PID: 3792 leapp.workflow.FactsCollection: Actor rpm_scanner has crashed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 573, in load
    ret = self._repo.load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libdnf/repo.py", line 397, in load
    return _repo.Repo_load(self)
libdnf._error.Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-8&arch=x86_64&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir [Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/leapp/repository/actor_definition.py", line 74, in _do_run
    actor_instance.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/leapp/actors/__init__.py", line 289, in run
    self.process(*args)
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/actors/rpmscanner/actor.py", line 20, in process
    rpmscanner.process()
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/actors/rpmscanner/libraries/rpmscanner.py", line 111, in process
    rpm_streams = map_modular_rpms_to_modules()
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/actors/rpmscanner/libraries/rpmscanner.py", line 87, in map_modular_rpms_to_modules
    modules = module_lib.get_modules()
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/libraries/module.py", line 57, in get_modules
    base = _create_or_get_dnf_base(base)
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/libraries/module.py", line 47, in _create_or_get_dnf_base
    base.fill_sack()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 405, in fill_sack
    self._add_repo_to_sack(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 140, in _add_repo_to_sack
    repo.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 580, in load
    raise dnf.exceptions.RepoError(str(e))
dnf.exceptions.RepoError: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-8&arch=x86_64&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir [Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds]



============================================================================================
Actor rpm_scanner unexpectedly terminated with exit code: 1 - Please check the above details
============================================================================================

Debug output written to /var/log/leapp/leapp-preupgrade.log

============================================================
                      REPORT OVERVIEW                       
============================================================

Reports summary:
    Errors:                      1
    Inhibitors:                  0
    HIGH severity reports:       0
    MEDIUM severity reports:     0
    LOW severity reports:        0
    INFO severity reports:       0

Before continuing consult the full report:
    A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.json
    A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt

============================================================
                   END OF REPORT OVERVIEW                   
============================================================

Answerfile has been generated at /var/log/leapp/answerfile

Content of leapp-report.txt is as follows:
Risk Factor: high (error)
Title: Actor rpm_scanner unexpectedly terminated with exit code: 1
Summary: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 573, in load
    ret = self._repo.load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libdnf/repo.py", line 397, in load
    return _repo.Repo_load(self)
libdnf._error.Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-8&arch=x86_64&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir [Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/leapp/repository/actor_definition.py", line 74, in _do_run
    actor_instance.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/leapp/actors/__init__.py", line 289, in run
    self.process(*args)
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/actors/rpmscanner/actor.py", line 20, in process
    rpmscanner.process()
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/actors/rpmscanner/libraries/rpmscanner.py", line 111, in process
    rpm_streams = map_modular_rpms_to_modules()
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/actors/rpmscanner/libraries/rpmscanner.py", line 87, in map_modular_rpms_to_modules
    modules = module_lib.get_modules()
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/libraries/module.py", line 57, in get_modules
    base = _create_or_get_dnf_base(base)
  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/libraries/module.py", line 47, in _create_or_get_dnf_base
    base.fill_sack()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 405, in fill_sack
    self._add_repo_to_sack(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 140, in _add_repo_to_sack
    repo.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 580, in load
    raise dnf.exceptions.RepoError(str(e))
dnf.exceptions.RepoError: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-8&arch=x86_64&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir [Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds]

Key: 474839c3aa4b047aadb49dc9f932f2d18033ced9
----------------------------------------


After I remove all the .repo files in /etc/yum.repos.d/, the command leapp preupgrade can be executed without a timeout error.
